# This iframe refuses to be transparent

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe, transparency

I have this iframe that will not be transparent for the life of me. I made the iframe allow transparency and also gave the body of the iframe a background-color:transparent;

```
<iframe src="about:blank" width="100%" height="200px" id="iframe1" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" onLoad="autoResize('iframe1');" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
</div>
```

This is in the iframe

```
html, body {
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

So I am really stumped on why this will not work! I read that the iframe cannot be styled from the outside, so I have to change styling somewhere in the iframe correct? But idk what it could be. What are the ways to make the background transparent? I have also tried it with background-color: none transparent; and background: none transparent; but nothing seems to work. Also tried to give it an filter:alpha(opacity=0) and opacity:0; still no luck. Anyone got any ideas?

You can view my problem here:

[kitchenova.com/mobile](http://kitchenova.com/mobile)

Run a search lets say for wine. Click on any of the image results and you will see my problem. I want to get rid of that white background on the iframe.

Comment: Have you tried background:transparent instead of just background-color?

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that in my question. @Will

Comment: Is that white edge your table?

Comment: Try removing or overriding the background set on `.ui-body-d, .ui-overlay-d` in `mobile.css line #85`. You might also want to remove the `box-shadow`.

Comment: @epascarello it is no the table, I removed the table and it was still not letting the iframe be transparent.

Comment: Walked the tree and found it to be `.ui-body-d,.ui-overlay-d` which has a bg image of white [which is what @showdev said!

Comment: That'll do it! Thank you so much @showdev, don't know how I didn't figure of trying that. You are awesome!!!! Can you post that as the answer so I could give you the credit for the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `mobile.css` on line 85, I see this:

```
.ui-body-d, .ui-overlay-d {
    background: linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #FFFFFF) repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
    color: #333333;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFFFFF;
}
```

Removing the background from this definition made the popup's background transparent.

You may want to add some background color to interior elements of the table so that the actual content area is not transparent.

You may also want to remove or override the `box-shadow` as the shadow appears square (not rounded corners):

```
.ui-overlay-shadow {
    box-shadow: 0 0 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```